# C# Selenium - como detectar que la autenticacion ha sido exitosa

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

Como puedo saber en que momento la autenticacion es exitosa despues de pasar el usuario y contraseña?

Quisiera parar la ejecucion y mostrar una vez que la conexion fue exitosa.

Este es mi codigo?

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("MiURL");
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));   

List<string> matchingLinks = new List<string>();

IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("test"));
userName.SendKeys(c);
IWebElement passwword = driver.FindElement(By.Name("test123"));
userPass.SendKeys(c);
userPass.Submit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que identificar en la página destino, algún elemento que te indique que la operación fue exitosa.

Ejemplo: si en la pantalla de destino del login hay un elemento `<div id="perfil_usuario">Algo</div>`, entonces búscalo. Si lo encuentras, el login habrá sido exitoso. De lo contrario, no.

Comment: Ah ok entonces si no concozco ese elemento no podre saber si fue existoso o no?

Comment: Correcto. A menos que la petición devuelva un STATUS CODE distinto cuando el login es exitoso. Puedes ver eso también. De una manera u otra: no hay magia. La respuesta es: depende de cómo está implementado el LOGIN.

Comment: Tiene sentido, muchas gracias!